# Liquibase: Error Cannot find data base driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I use liquibase 3.6.1 to work with Mysql database. 
I use the lib "mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar", I got the below error when using **diff** command:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find data
base driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

If I use the lib "mysql-connector-java-6.0.2.jar" I got the another error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/mysql/cj/jdbc/Driver, offset=6
```

How can I fix this ?